# Could not find a declaration file for module '@types/connect-multiparty'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this problem that I have not been able to solve, any suggestions?

Try to unlink the library and using the `$ npm install @types/connect-multiparty` command:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try looking this package up: https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/. It seems that it's not available.  Perhaps try to create the definitions yourself.

P.S. It's not advices to use this package, the author advices to use the multiparty API directly in the Express.

Comment: Could you try setting the registry to `http` ? Using the command `npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` ?

Answer (score 0):

The package is called `connect-multiparty`, so you need to run:

```
$ npm i connect-multiparty
```